# Where can I download a 6 man endgame tablebase

Tags: engines, analysis, software, endgame

I just cannot seem to find a link to a 6 man download endgame tablebase from syzygy.  If anyone could provide me with a link it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can buy them from Chessbase - https://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/endspiel_turbo_4?ref=RF36-BU6JTC6QHH

Comment: http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/tablebases-online/

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to download 80+GB of data there is a torrent link here - http://oics.olympuschess.com/tracker/index.php. Also includes linkls for Nalimov, Scorpio and Gaviota.

Alternatively (and more work) Ronald de Man (syzygy developer) has published software for generating these tablebases (up to 6 man) on Github - https://github.com/syzygy1/tb.

Comment: I think I downloaded full syzygy (+-150GB) for around 24 hours.