# Free tablebase generator software?

Tags: programming, tablebases

I'd like to play a bit with fairy tablebases (Vaclav Kotesovec published quite a few) and am far too lazy to program them anew, especially as I wouldn't wonder if there is free code floating around, and I just would have to find where the PARAMETER N=8 statement hides. (BTW, the results can be quite interesting: as I suspected anyway, Q vs R is drawn on a very large board, and with the right size even a mutual zugzwang exists.)

Still, I never was lucky googling. Do you have any resources? (GitHub, chess programming BBS, maybe even scientific papers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I never was lucky googling

No need to google. All you needed to do was search on this site and you could have come up with [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/where-can-i-download-a-6-man-endgame-tablebase/18886#18886) which amongst other things says:

> Ronald de Man (syzygy developer) has published software for generating these tablebases (up to 6 man) on [Github](https://github.com/syzygy1/tb)

Comment: The formulation of that question would never have suggested me that the code is there too, so it would never have turned up on my radar, so many THX for the link - although I now must hack some C code...